# Disable the whole jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using jsTree and have a form on the right of it based on the selected node that can be edited/saved. The goal is to prevent the user from clicking anywhere else on the tree while they are editing the form.

Is there any way to temp disable/enable the tree functionality while still keeping the tree visually available?

I tried using the `disable_node(obj)` method and apply it to the root of the tree but doesn't seem to be a solution.

Any suggestions? Or this is not a possible feature for the jsTree lib?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, thanks for your reply. what I ended up doing is disable the div container that my tree was in. I will mark it as the accepted answer as its a good way of doing it and its actually better for me just to disable the tree vs all components in the div. Thanks again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To disable selected node do it this way:

```
var node = $("#tree").jstree().get_selected();
$("#tree").jstree().disable_node(node);
```

To disable all nodes use:

```
$('#tree li').each( function() {
    $("#tree").jstree().disable_node(this.id);
})
```

UPDATED

I didn't find a way to prevent opening a disabled node so I'm just disabling all the children of a closed node too.

See demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/Lgr0q403/)

Comment: 1 The fiddle does not seem relate to tree disabling at all. 2 At least with jstree 3 this method only disable open nodes, but you can still click on "open" icon on disabled nodes and open subtrees that will not be disabled

Comment: Don't know if it is still relevant, but I found this solution that disables all nodes: https://groups.google.com/g/jstree/c/EFXhEyDnX_g

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** As pointed out by @charles *disabling the nodes doesn't disable the menu plugin (at least with a custom menu) or drag'n'drop* - Added point 4 to take care of this

To disable the whole tree

1. Disable all rendered nodes - disable each node by id *or* get an array of ids to do a single call to "disable_node"
2. Forbid the opening of new nodes - intercept and block the click event on the open icon
3. Forbid the opening of new nodes with double click - modify the current tree settings
4. If the tree is user modifiable in any way, temporary disable all modifications setting `core.check_callback = false`

**Note** The point 2 is base on undocumented features and (given the history of the jstree plugin) will probably not work on future releases

*See the snippet for a demo*

```js
var data1 = [{
  "id": "W",
  "text": "World",
  "state": { "opened": true },
  "children": [{"text": "Asia"}, 
               {"text": "Africa"}, 
               {"text": "Europe",
                "state": { "opened": false },
                "children": [ "France","Germany","UK" ]
  }]
}];

$('#Tree').jstree({ 
    core: {data: data1, 
    check_callback: true
  }, 
  plugins: ['dnd','contextmenu','checkbox']
})

function DisableFlawed() {
  // this is not enough 
  $('#Tree li.jstree-node').each(function() {
    $('#Tree').jstree("disable_node", this.id)
  })
}  
function Disable() {
  // disable visible nodes
  $('#Tree li.jstree-node').each(function() {
    $('#Tree').jstree("disable_node", this.id)
  })
  // block open new nodes
  $('#Tree i.jstree-ocl')
  .off('click.block')
  .on('click.block', function() {
    return false;
    });
  // eventually... dbl click
  $('#Tree').jstree().settings.core.dblclick_toggle = false;
  // eventually... block all edits
  $('#Tree').jstree().settings.core.check_callback = false;
}  
function Enable() {
  // enable again visible nodes
  $('#Tree li.jstree-node').each(function() {
    $('#Tree').jstree("enable_node", this.id)
  });
  // ublock open new nodes
  $('#Tree i.jstree-ocl')
  //
  .off('click.block');
  // eventually... dbl click
  $('#Tree').jstree().settings.core.dblclick_toggle = true;
  // eventually... unblock all edits
  // set to true OR reset to whatever user defined function you are using
  $('#Tree').jstree().settings.core.check_callback = true;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="DisableFlawed()">Disable (bad)</button>
<button onclick="Disable()">Disable (ok)</button>
<button onclick="Enable()">Enable</button>
<div id="Tree"></div>
```

Comment: This works for me, as opposed to other answers here that don't disable all those interactions. Only hang is that the tree area doesn't LOOK disabled, which you may want to change, set a darker background etc.

Comment: @enigment having all the nodes grayed is enough for me (even too much indeed). But setting the color of the container area is easy - probably the best way is add a specific class

Comment: yes, agree, What surprises me is that jsTree doesn't have this functionality built in. We can't be the only people who want to make a whole tree read only.

Comment: @enigment it was a feature of rel 1. Probably caused some unexpected problem, so it was left beihnd

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Nikolay Ermakov's answer, disabling the nodes doesn't disable the menu plugin (at least with a custom menu) or drag'n'drop. If you want to do so, you need to add an extra check in these functions (tested with JsTree 3.2.1)

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    // ...
    contextmenu: {
        items: customMenu
    },
    dnd: {
        is_draggable: function (node) {
            return !node[0].state.disabled;
        }
    },
});

function customMenu(node)
{
    if (node.state.disabled)
        return false;

    // usual menu generation code
}
```

Another way is to use something [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) to do some general blocking outside of jsTree.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
// get an instance of jstree.
var tree = $.jstree.create('#tree', { ... });

// disable all nodes with one line.
tree.disable_node(tree.get_json(null, { flat: true }));
```